# Import pyffmpeg. Python 2.6, Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, video-capture, python-2.6, pyffmpeg

I have problem in connection with import pyyfmpeg library. I'm using a python 2.6 version. Apart from that I've installed ffmpeg for my Windows version - 64 bit. Of coruse I added path to ffmpeg to environment variable.

If I try to import, a pyyfmpeg to my project then I will get information that there is no module named a pyyfmpeg, although I copied whole content of pyyfmpeg to ...Lib/Site-packages

Any Ideas why it's not working?

Comment: That's *not* how you install Python packages. But are you sure you didn't just misspell the package name? You did every time you used it in your question, though not in your title.

Comment: @Cairnarvon what is the correct way to do it?